# Один WebView для всех ссылок приложения

Tags: android, url, webview

Хочу сделать один WebView для всех ссылок в приложении.

```
public class EX extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ex);
        web = findViewById(R.id.web);

        web.loadUrl("https://ez.vnmu.edu.ua/");
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                }
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Как переделать код так что бы при нажатие на любую ссылку в приложении открывалась встроенное в приложение WebView. без запроса других браузеров

Смотрите я хочу сделать что бы не использовать intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.ua")); startActivity(intent); а что бы ссылку которую хранит кнопка сразу открывало моё webview.

В данного webView уже задан url а я хочу что бы при переходе на это активити url задавало прошлое активити а не уже было заданное.

WebView сейчас имеет статичную ссылку при переходе на него будет отображаться только она а я хочу что бы он отображал ссылку которою ему задаю с любого места программы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы открывалась Ваша активность без альтернатив - нужно вызывать её явным интентом (с указанием её класса):

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.ua"),
                                            getApplicationContext(), EX.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

Чтобы в `WebView` открылась переданная ссылка нужно взять её из интента и загрузить:

```
    web = findViewById(R.id.web);

    web.loadUrl(getIntent().getDataString());
```

Comment: можно ли аналогично сделать с картами MapView ? или там совсем другой механизм работы?

Comment: можно напишите пожалуйста как ещё реализовать на картах данную часть потому что `.loadUrl` не подходит к `MapView`

Comment: Я карты не использовал - не могу ничего посоветовать. Посмотрите документацию и примеры, спросите в чате или новый вопрос задайте.

Comment: Вы случайно не сталкивались с проблемой когда WebView не может загрузить сайт.... Сайт грузится грузится но так и не загружается... Что добавить надо? Я бы создал отдельный вопрос но проблема в том что уже задал с MapView